# Qt. Is it possible to use local variable in connect SLOT()?

Tags: qt, signals-slots

```
void SomeClass::mySlot(MyClass *var){
    ...
}

void SomeClass::SomeFunction(){
    MyClass *myVar;
    QPushButton *button = new QPushButton(this);
    connect(button, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(mySlot(myVar)));
}
```

I want mySlot to receive myVar when the button is clicked. 
is it possible to do something like that? I don't want to store myVar pointer in SomeClass.

**update (my solution):**

```
void SomeClass::mySlot(){
    QPushButton *button = static_cast<QPushButton*>(sender());  
    MyClass *myVar = qobject_cast<MyClass*>(qvariant_cast<QObject *>(button->property("myVar")));
    ...
}

void SomeClass::SomeFunction(){
    MyClass *myVar;
    QPushButton *button = new QPushButton(this);
    button->setProperty("myVar", QVariant::fromValue((QObject*)myVar));
    connect(button, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(mySlot()));
}
```

Comment: Your solution can't possibly work. The `connect` call will fail.

Comment: I was mistaken while copy-paste. I corrected `connect`. Thanks for your comment!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it is not possible. You can use a slot which discard some parameters but not a slot which have more parameters than the signal. Plus you cannot pass a variable when connecting a slot.

Comment: Effectively the connect function is just matching a signature of the function calls.

Comment: This answer isn't really correct. It is possible to do what @Eddie wants - with some restrictions, but it's not "impossible".

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with [`QSignalMapper`](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qsignalmapper.html) (see the example there for usage) with some restrictions, but you need to be very careful with object lifetimes.

```
QSignalMapper *signalMapper = new QSignalMapper(this);
MyClass *myVar = new ...;

QPushButton *button = new QPushButton(this);
connect(button, SIGNAL(clicked()), signalMapper, SLOT(map()));
signalMapper->setMapping(button, myVar);

connect(signalMapper, SIGNAL(mapped(MyClass*)),
         this, SIGNAL(MySlot(MyClass*)));
```

(Note the `MyClass` needs to be derived from `QObject` or `QWidget`.)

This will work as long as the object pointed to by `myVar` remains valid (i.e. is not deleted), but if you don't store a pointer to that object somewhere, you won't be able to delete it easily - so you could have a memory leak. (If you hold on to the signal mapper and the button pointer, you can recover that object with the `mapping` member of `QSignalMapper`.)

On the other hand, the following **will not work**:

```
QSignalMapper *signalMapper = new QSignalMapper(this);
MyClass myVar;
...
signalMapper->setMapping(button, &myVar); // WRONG
...
```

This cannot work because in that case, the object referenced by `myVar` is destroyed when `someFunction` ends, so the slot will receive an invalid pointer, which leads to undefined behavior (i.e. anything could happen - bug, crash, things appearing to work sometimes not others, ...).

Comment: Nice solution. but I decided to use the following: 
    button->setProperty("myVar", QVariant::fromValue((QObject*)myVar));  (before connect)          
    MyClass *myVar = qobject_cast<MyClass*>(qvariant_cast<QObject *>(static_cast<QPushButton*>(sender())->property("myVar")));      (in slot)